# One or more files could not be uploaded. See the Log file for more details in sitecore 7.1

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.1

I get this "One or more files could not be uploaded. See the Log file for more details." error when i tried to upload an image file using firefox browser. In other browsers (IE and Chrome), it works fine. I checked whether WebDav.config causing the issue and i removed this config but didn't help. Also, I checked the anonymous access on Applications/FlashUpload and /Applications/Media.

Does anyone encountered this scenario? 
May i know what is the cause.

Sitecore version : sitecore 7.1
Firefox 27.0.1

Thanks, 
Mohan

Comment: Yeah I'm hitting that now. Same error. I'm on FF 28 but I imagine they're similar enough. The answer by user459491 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Please try modifying the following settings:

```
     <setting name="Upload.Classic" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

answer from user459491 will solve the problem, but it simply changes the controls used for file downloads. I had same issue and the reason was that our website used windows authentication and asp.net authentication. The solution is explained here:

http://maesitus-sitecore.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/sitecore-media-upload-is-not-working.html

"I have then lodged a ticket with Sitecore support. Few days later they come back with a solution that is to enable "Anonymous" authentication in IIS for ‘/sitecore/shell/Applications/FlashUpload’ and ‘/sitecore/shell/Applications/Media’."